# Why does not this UNION ALL work?

Tags: mysql

i create a query to pass the data of one table to other but return an error:

> Símbolo (token) inesperado. (near "UNION ALL" at position 150)

here my query:

```
insert into vencimientos_arba(impuestoId, impuesto, vencimiento)
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo1) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo2) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo3) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo4) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo5) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo6) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo7) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo8) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo9) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo10) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, CONCAT('2017-', anticipo11) AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, anticipo12 AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
UNION ALL
select id, concepto, anual AS concatenar from ingresos_brutos
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike some other database engines, in MySQL, we need to use the `VALUES` keyword with `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES
SELECT columns FROM table
 UNION ALL 
SELECT columns FROM table
...
```

This is why we see the "unexpected token" error shown in the question.

Comment: Something is wrong in its syntax near 'select id, concepto, CONCAT (' 2017- ', anticipo1) AS concatenar of ingresos_brut' on line 3 ? (the unexpected token has gone)

Comment: Is that the exact error? I see `CONCAT(danticipo12)` which doesn't match the other column names in the query. Could this be the source of the error? Or maybe you're using `id` instead of `impuestoId` in the `SELECT` statements?

Comment: if it is the exact error that it returns, and I have already corrected "danticipo12" for "anticipo12" but it does not change anything

Comment: What about `id` instead of `impuestoId` in the `SELECT` columns?

Comment: in my table `ingresos_brutos` is `id`, in `vencimientos_arba` is `impuestoId`

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was wrong. Just did some testing and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` *is* the correct syntax for MySQL (no `VALUES` needed), at least with MySQL 5.6. I'll update the answer...surprised that no one caught that.